# Spring Tool Suit: Trying to delete a folder within a web app

Tags: spring, eclipse, directory, spring-tool-suite

Within my project I need to delete a folder, but everytime I try to I get this message:

Resource 'ProjectTemplate/node_modules' is out of sync with file system

I had issues deleting the entire folder, that I tried to delete individual folders within node_modules with success, but now I get another error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried right clicking the project folder and selecting refresh?

Comment: I have tried that a number of times then tried to delete with no luck, but tried again and it allowed me to delete the folder.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click the folder and select Refresh.  I tried that multiple times, but another attempt allowed me to delete the folder.